# Dismiss UIDatePicker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uidatepicker

I add a `UIDatePicker` as input view to `UITextField`

```
UIDatePicker    *oBirth;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat;

_editingField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame : CGRectMake(80, 12, 215, 25)];    
dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat : @"dd/MM/yyyy"];

oBirth = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame : CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 45)];
oBirth.date = [dateFormat dateFromString : sField];
NSLog(@"%@", oBirth.subviews);
[oBirth addTarget : self
           action : @selector(updateDate:)
 forControlEvents : UIControlEventValueChanged];
[oBirth addTarget : self
           action : @selector(dismissDate:)
 forControlEvents : UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
[oBirth setDatePickerMode : UIDatePickerModeDate];
_editingField.tag = 1;
_editingField.inputView = oBirth;
```

How can I dismiss the `UIDatePicker` without creating an invisible view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
[_editingField resignFirstResponder];
```

**Edit**

For `dismissDate` not being called.

Remove this piece of code

```
[oBirth addTarget : self
           action : @selector(dismissDate:)
 forControlEvents : UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

And add this

```
     // single tap gesture recognizer
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognize = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissDate:)];
        tapGestureRecognize.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognize];
```

Your callback

```
- (void)dismissDate:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    NSLog(@"Resign your responder");
}
```

Comment: I tried in `-(void) dismissDate:(id)sender` but it doesn't have effects

Comment: It'll work. It's just your `dismissDate:` is not being called. Put some log there..

Comment: When I tap in other `UITextfield` it never call `dissmissDate:` it call other callback of `UITextfield` it's normal I think. But when I tap anywhere else in my `superview` it's not detected and then I cannot `resignFirstResponder`

Comment: The TouchUpOutside event is not like if you touch outside of date picker it'll be called. That's not the behaviour of TouchUpOutside. For that you should use hit test to check which view has been touched..